# returning inherited class instead of superclass in method overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, builder, fluent, overriding

I have a certain class structure that looks something like this:

```
class Parent {
    public Parent(int property) { /* use property */}
}
class Son extends Parent {
    public Son(int parentProperty, String sonProperty) { 
        super(parentProperty);
        /* use son property */ 
    }
}
```

I'd like to create builders for both these classes such that:

```
class ParentBuilder {
    protected int parentProperty;

    public ParentBuilder parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {
        parentPropertyValue = parentPropertyValue;
        return this;
    }

    public Parent build() {
        return new Parent(parentProperty);
    }
}
class SonBuilder extends ParentBuilder {
    private String sonProperty;

    public SonBuilder sonProperty(String sonProperty) {
        this.sonProperty = sonProperty;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Son build() {
        return new Son(parentProperty, sonProperty);
    }
}
```

but this causes the following problem:

```
SonBuilder sonBuilder = new SonBuilder();
sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").build(); // this works and creates Son
sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").parentProperty(1).build(); // this works and creates Parent instead of Son
sonBuilder.parentProperty(1).sonProperty("aString").build(); // this doesn't work
```

I realize I'm nitpicking and this could be solved with just not returning `this` (i.e. without method chaining), but I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution.

**edit**

It seems that the word "elegant" is a source for a bit of confusion.

By "elegant" I mean a solution which allows for method chaining and does not involve casting.

Comment: I'm a C++ guy so not sure, but would your 3rd line really create a `Parent` object? Or a `Son` object and return it as `Parent` reference?

Comment: @king_nak yes, I was actually asking if it was possible to return the current class (`Parent` or `Son`) when returning `this`. Without casting and without forgoing the method chaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First point

```
sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").parentProperty(1).build();
```

> this works and creates Parent instead of Son

It is expected as `parentProperty()` returns a `ParentBuilder` :

```
public ParentBuilder parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {...
```

And `ParentBuilder.build()` creates a `Parent` :

```
public Parent build() {
    return new Parent(parentProperty);
}
```

Second point

```
sonBuilder.parentProperty(1).sonProperty("aString").build(); // this doesn't work
```

As said in the first point, `parentProperty()` returns a `ParentBuilder`.
And `ParentBuilder` of course doesn't have a `sonProperty()` method.
So it cannot compile.

> I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution.

An elegant solution would be not make `SonBuilder`  inherited `ParentBuilder`  but compose with a `ParentBuilder`  field.
For example :

```
class SonBuilder {

    private String sonProperty;
    private ParentBuilder parentBuilder = new ParentBuilder();

    public SonBuilder sonProperty(String sonProperty) {
      this.sonProperty = sonProperty;
      return this;
    }

    public SonBuilder parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {
      parentBuilder.parentProperty(parentPropertyValue);
      return this;
    }

    public Son build() {
      return new Son(parentBuilder.parentProperty, sonProperty);
    }
}
```

You can so create the `Son` in this way :

```
SonBuilder sonBuilder = new SonBuilder();
Son son = sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").parentProperty(1).build();
```

Comment: I like it, a bit of extra coding but it's typesafe and has no functional leakage, will use.

Comment: It is its big advantage : no leakage/coupling between the builders. This other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198377/270371 provides a shorter way but has this drawback. I suppose that according to the level of class stability, the one or the second one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the parent property to exist in your `build()` method.

```
return (parentProperty == null) ? new Parent(parentProperty, sonProperty) : new Son(sonProperty);
```

Comment: Would that be 'elegant'?

Comment: parent property will always exist, it is part of `ParentBuilder`, the problem is that when I set `parentProprerty` via `parentProperty(...)` I'm getting back a `ParentBuilder` instead of `SonBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be considered as elegant, but you can use casting:

```
SonBuilder sonBuilder = new SonBuilder();
Son son1 = sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").build();
Son son2 = (Son) sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").parentProperty(1).build();
Son son3 = ((SonBuilder) sonBuilder.parentProperty(1)).sonProperty("aString").build();
```

Comment: honestly, this is probably the shortest way, with the least code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Override `parentProperty` in `SonBuilder`:

```
@Override
public SonBuilder parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {
    super.parentProperty(parentPropertyValue);
    return this;
}
```

This is safe because (and as long as) `super.parentProperty` returns `this`. If you have immutable builders instead, your override would also be different.

Or use generics:

```
abstract class AParentBuilder<T extends Parent> {
    protected int parentProperty;

    public AParentBuilder<T> parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {
        parentPropertyValue = parentPropertyValue;
        return this;
    }

    abstract public T build();
}

class ParentBuilder extends AParentBuilder<Parent> {
    @Override
    public Parent build() {
        return new Parent(parentProperty);
    }
}

abstract class ASonBuilder<T extends Son> extends AParentBuilder<T> {
    private String sonProperty;

    public ASonBuilder<T> sonProperty(String sonProperty) {
        this.sonProperty = sonProperty;
        return this;
    }
}

class SonBuilder extends ASonBuilder<Son> {
    @Override
    public Son build() {
        return new Son(parentProperty, sonProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is using covariant return type in the subclass method.

Keep `SonBuilder` extend `ParentBuilder` but override `parentProperty()` to return a `SonBuilder` :

```
@Override
public SonBuilder parentProperty(int parentPropertyValue) {
   super.parentProperty(parentPropertyValue);
   return this;
}
```

You can still create the Son in this way :

```
SonBuilder sonBuilder = new SonBuilder();
Son son = sonBuilder.sonProperty("aString").parentProperty(1).build();
```

as now `parentProperty(1)` invokes the subclass method that returns a `SonBuilder`.

**This solution may seem fine but it has a drawback.**
It creates a strong coupling between the subclass builder and the base builder.
At each time you add a setProperty method in the parent builder, you have to override it in the subclass.
Otherwise, you would still have the initial problem : a code that doesn't compile or it would instantiate the Parent instead of the Son class.
For classes that don't change at all, it may be acceptable.
Otherwise, it should be avoided.

The solution using the composition  is better as it allows the `SonBuilder` to evolve at its own rhythm and with its own rules.